Tell conan to use my installation of cmake instead of compiling one from scratch
For my project I'm using conan version 2.5.0, I'm also working on NixOS. After setting up everything and trying to install the depedencies of my project, I found out that conan compiles and tries to use CMake for one dependency:
➜ conan install conanfile.txt --build=missing
======== Installing packages ========

-------- Downloading 14 packages --------
cmake/3.30.5: Retrieving package 63fead0844576fc02943e16909f08fcdddd6f44b from remote 'conancenter'
cmake/3.30.5: Downloading 44.0MB conan_package.tgz
cmake/3.30.5: Decompressing 44.0MB conan_package.tgz
cmake/3.30.5: Package installed 63fead0844576fc02943e16909f08fcdddd6f44b
cmake/3.30.5: Downloaded package revision e7bca794d221e787672baaed17ddbc3f

# ...

cmake/3.30.5: Appending PATH environment variable: /home/jorge/.conan2/p/cmake472b88369c9bf/p/bin
cmake/3.30.5: Appending PATH environment variable: /home/jorge/.conan2/p/cmake472b88369c9bf/p/bin

# ...

-------- Installing package joltphysics/3.0.1 (21 of 32) --------
joltphysics/3.0.1: Building from source
joltphysics/3.0.1: Package joltphysics/3.0.1:3f7fd406790cc7bc8b3903b7793684e958c409a3
joltphysics/3.0.1: Copying sources to build folder
joltphysics/3.0.1: Building your package in /home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/b
joltphysics/3.0.1: Calling generate()
joltphysics/3.0.1: Generators folder: /home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/b/build/Release/generators
joltphysics/3.0.1: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
joltphysics/3.0.1: CMakeToolchain generated: /home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/b/build/Release/generators/CMakePresets.json
joltphysics/3.0.1: Generating aggregated env files
joltphysics/3.0.1: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.sh', 'conanrun.sh']
joltphysics/3.0.1: Calling build()
joltphysics/3.0.1: Apply patch (conan): Fix CMakeLists: no warnings as errors, allow shared, add install target, and add profile & debug_renderer options
joltphysics/3.0.1: Running CMake.configure()
joltphysics/3.0.1: RUN: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/p" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "/home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/b/src/Build"
Could not start dynamically linked executable: cmake
NixOS cannot run dynamically linked executables intended for generic
linux environments out of the box. For more information, see:
https://nix.dev/permalink/stub-ld

joltphysics/3.0.1: ERROR:
Package '3f7fd406790cc7bc8b3903b7793684e958c409a3' build failed
joltphysics/3.0.1: WARN: Build folder /home/jorge/.conan2/p/b/joltpc788376fa4e1a/b/build/Release
ERROR: joltphysics/3.0.1: Error in build() method, line 141
    cmake.configure(build_script_folder=os.path.join(self.source_folder, "Build"))
    ConanException: Error 127 while executing

This is a big no-no on NixOS.
How do I prevent conan from doing this? I have CMake 3.29.2 installed.
Here is my current conan profile:
➜  conan profile show
Host profile:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=13
os=Linux

Build profile:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=13
os=Linux

this is the conanfile.txt of my project:
[requires]
eastl/3.21.12
joltphysics/3.0.1
diligent-core/api.252009

[generators]
CMakeDeps


The Conan 2.x has a large support for customization, including your CMake used. Your current log shows CMake installed from Conan as a tool requirement. In case you want to use your installed system CMake, you can use platform-tool-requires:
# default profile
...
[platform_tool_requires]
cmake/3.30.5

You profile will tell Conan to use your system CMake when consuming cmake/3.30.5, but you can do it for any version too:
# default profile
...
[platform_tool_requires]
cmake/*


I would suggest adding CMakeToolchain to your conanfile.txt too, so Conan will generate a CMake toolchain file, matching your profile to CMake configuration. For instance, CMake uses Debug by default as build type, but Conan uses Release, this mismatch may cause misconfiguration and build errors. You take a look on the official tutorial as example, how to consume the toolchain file generated by Conan.

Thanks for the answer. Despite adding [platform_tool_requires] to my default profile, joltphysics/3.0.1 insists on asking for CMake 3.30.5. Maybe this happens because my CMake is 3.29.2?

You need to check you Conan log if cmake/3.30.5 - Platform shows there, that means, Conan will using system CMake, not from tool requires. Otherwise, it's a mismatch in your profile related to the cmake version listed in platform_tool_requires.
